# Insomnia REST Client - Set "Content-Type" for multipart/form-data

Tags: rest, rest-client, onenote-api, insomnia

**TL;DR**
How can I set the `Content-Type` headers for each *individual* file/input/text in a `multipart/form-data` request (in Insomnia)?

I'm trying to POST to the OneNote API ([HTTP description](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/onenotedev/2017/07/07/onenote-ink-beta-apis/)) using the Insomnia Rest Client. Per the documentation, I need to submit a `multipart/form-data` request with one file/text with headers:

`Content-Type: text/html
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=presentation`

and another with the headers:

`Content-Type: application/inkml+xml
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=presentation-onenote-inkml`

Here is a screenshot of what I am trying:
[image: headers]
As you can see, the API returns an error with `No Content-Type` leading me to believe that the `Content-Type` header is not set. The debug information is below:
[image: debug]
The POST data is hidden, which does not allow me to see the `Content-Type`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Solution:** When you use `POST` with the **file** arguments, this works. I don't know why.

[image: solution image]

Comment: If you'd click the button 'bulk edit' button, what does the code look file look like?

Answer (score 1):

The "Generate Code" command may help you find the cause of the problem.
The command generates a program code, which contains the essential part of the POST data.

[image: For example:]